# Solution to use limit in mongodb find without using MongoCursor->limit()?

Tags: php, mongodb

I work with mongodb and i have a simple request to do. I use "find" and i want to limit the result it gets. I have seen the functions "skip" and "limit" of MongoCursor but i want to use the $limit and $skip properties in the query and not with the cursor to limit the data returned.

In the mongodb documentation that seems possible but my request return nothing if I try like this :

```
$myMongoDB->myCollection->find(array('type' => 'test', '$limit' => 10);
```

Or :

```
$myMongoDB->myCollection->find(array('$query' => array('type' => 'test'), '$limit' => 10);
```

Anyone could help me to see what i do wrong ?

Thank's for help.

PS : and sorry for the quality of my english...

Comment: You know there is no differnce between doing it via functions and query modifiers right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why you want to do this however:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('type' => 'test'));
$cursor->addOption( '$maxScan', 10 );
```

`$maxScan` is `$limit` and `$orderby` is `$sort`.

Reference: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-modifier/

Comment: I know how to use this with the cursor. But, in that case, the data is returned from the DB in the cursor and I want just, for example, 10 elements, not the entire selection. You see what i mean or it is just that I miss something ?

Comment: @Naelyth What do you mean? The entire selection is 10 elements in this case?

Comment: @Naelyth Aha I think I know what your confusion is, the query does not run when you issue the `find()` command, the query runs when you iterate the cursor. This means that the query has not been sent to MongoDB and a cursor created until you interate it. This is in contrast to SQL techs which do all this when you call `find()`. No query is issued until you iterate

Comment: Ok, that's what I missed... Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @Naelyth anytime glad to have helpd, it threw me too at first